# Diffeomorphism invariance for derivative of scalar fields

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, gauge-invariance, covariance, diffeomorphism-invariance

In GR, it is well-known that the gravitational stress-energy tensor is a pseudotensor, i.e. it is not gauge-invariant. To make it gauge-invariant one needs to take it under average integral $\langle \rangle$, where one can  integrate by parts  and throw away the boundary terms .

Here, I wonder what if I add to GR a term like this:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\partial_{\alpha}\varphi \partial_{\beta}\varphi
\end{equation}

Is (1) gauge-invariant in GR ?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term has two tensor indices so should be gauge *covariant*, not invariant. And your transformation in (A.1) verifies that it transforms as a (covariant) rank two object under the infinitesimal gauge transformation.

In an action all terms should be scalars, i.e., have no free spacetime indices. So you should be thinking about the term $\partial^{\alpha} \varphi \partial_{\alpha} \varphi$. Then you'll find this is gauge invariant.

Comment: The term (1) appears in the energy-momentum pseudotensor of a scalar-tensor theory of gravity, not in the action.

Comment: And field equations (with free indices) shouldn't be invariant, they should be covariant. The term you listed (1) **is** gauge covariant. I talked about the action because a (pseudo-)invariant action always leads to covariant field equations, so the discussion is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about, OP.
There are several different definitions of stress-energy for gravity, under different conditions, different approximations.

In full GR, gravity isn't usually described by a stress-energy tensor. Matter fields are described by stress-energy tensor

$$ T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{|g|}} \frac{\delta S_{\text{matter}}}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}}. $$

That is a true tensor, not tensor density. This is because the density factor of $\sqrt{|g|}$ in the action is canceled against the denominator.

Gravity itself is instead described by the Einstein tensor, which is defined by the same formula, except there's the Einstein-Hilbert action instead of the matter action. You could say that the stress-energy tensor for gravity is

$$ T_{\mu \nu} = - \frac{c^4}{8 \pi G} \left( R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu \nu} \right). $$

In this interpretation, Einstein's equations can be thought of as requiring the **total** stress-energy tensor of matter and gravity to vanish.

The Einstein tensor is still a true tensor.

You are probably talking about either some other special-relativistic theory of gravity that operates with Lorentz pseudo-tensors, or linearized gravity around the flat space-time solution of Special Relativity, or something of the sort (please clarify context!)

P.S. The term $\partial_{\mu} \phi \partial_{\nu} \phi$ is a true tensor, as long as $\phi$ is a scalar.